# Adding records to database using for loop

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have a problem, I would like to add some people to the database in a loop, but my question makes it added there is only one person (first) the loop, even though the form introduce 4.

```
    $query = "INSERT INTO egzaminy (id,data_egz,kat_egz,id_osob) VALUES (' ','".$_POST['data']."','".$_POST['kategoria']."','')";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die("Błąd dodawania egzaminu");
    $id = mysql_insert_id(); 
    if ($result == 1){

        $quer = "INSERT INTO kursanci (id,imie,nazwisko,data_ost_egz,wynik,podejscie,instruktor,pojazd,id_egz) VALUES (' ','".$_POST['imie']."','".$_POST['nazwisko']."','".$_POST['data']."','".$_POST['wynik']."','".$_POST['podejscie']."','".$_POST['instruktor']."','".$_POST['pojazd']."','".$id."')";
        $res = mysql_query($quer) or die (mysql_error());
        $id_osoby = mysql_insert_id();
        print_r($id_osoby);
    }       
for($i=1;$i<=12;$i++){
    if (isset($_POST['imie'.$i])){
        $quer = "INSERT INTO kursanci (id,imie,nazwisko,data_ost_egz,wynik,podejscie,instruktor,pojazd,id_egz) VALUES (' ','".$_POST['imie'.$i]."','".$_POST['nazwisko'.$i]."','".$_POST['data']."','".$_POST['wynik'.$i]."','".$_POST['podejscie'.$i]."','".$_POST['instruktor'.$i]."','".$_POST['pojazd'.$i]."','".$id."')";
        echo "INSERT INTO kursanci (id,imie,nazwisko,data_ost_egz,wynik,podejscie,instruktor,pojazd,id_egz) VALUES (' ','".$_POST['imie'.$i]."','".$_POST['nazwisko'.$i]."','".$_POST['data']."','".$_POST['wynik'.$i]."','".$_POST['podejscie'.$i]."','".$_POST['instruktor'.$i]."','".$_POST['pojazd'.$i]."','".$id."')";
        echo "<br>";
        print_r("I = ".$i);
        $res = mysql_query($quer) or die (mysql_error());
        $id_osoby."-".$i = mysql_insert_id();
        print_r($id_osoby."-".$i);
    }
}
```

I don't have any errors

Comment: Is `id` field a primary key and not null in your tables? @Kubol

Comment: If yur problem solve than chose the best answer which solve yur problem and mark as accepted

Answer (score 0):

Don`t use mysql_query. Read, please, about PDO http://php.net/manual/pl/book.pdo.php and try it.

Also try don`t write id in your table, or check that in the table ID is AUTO INCREMENT Field 
(ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,)

Answer (score 0):

Ist of all please use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` extension because `mysql_*` is deprecated and not available in PHP 7.

**Now, as per your comments:**

> *@AnkiiG, yes... – Kubol*

id column is `PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT` so can't insert empty string.

**From the question:**

> *it added there is only one person (first) the loop, even though the
>   form introduce 4.*

If form give you four records than `for()` loop will fail in 5th iteration.
and it will give you undefined index notice because you are using `$i<=12`.